# redraw if cursor not in range

Tags: vim

I like having the `nnoremap` for `n` to `nzz`, but when the next match is right below the one I am right now, or two lines below, I get disoriented when I press `n`.
I would like a command to do what `zz` does, but only if the cursor is currently not in the middle 10 lines.
can you help me?

Comment: final solution for my vimrc, thanks to Peter Rincker and ZyX.  
https://gist.github.com/3901445

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple solution you may want to look into setting `'scrolloff'` to something large. This does not actually solve your question exactly but it is something very simple so you may want to try this first.

If that isn't satisfactory then we can try the heavier handed approach and put a function in your `~/.vimrc`.

```
nnoremap <silent> n :call Recenter('n', 10)<cr>
nnoremap <silent> N :call Recenter('N', 10)<cr>

function! Recenter(cmd, tolerance)
  let ws = line('w0')
  let distance = line('w$') - ws
  exe 'norm! ' . a:cmd
  let tolerance = a:tolerance / 2
  let current_offset = line('.') - line('w0')
  if line('w0') != ws || (current_offset < (distance/2-tolerance) || current_offset > (distance/2+tolerance))
    norm! zz
  endif
endfunction
```

For more information see:

```
:h 'scrolloff'
:h line()
:h zz
```

Comment: And `:h abs()` for replacing `(current_offset < (distance/2-tolerance) || current_offset > (distance/2+tolerance))` with one condition.

Comment: what i did is this ```nnoremap n n:call Recenter(15)<CR>  
nnoremap N N:call Recenter(15)<CR>  
  
function! Recenter(tolerance)  
 if (abs(winline()-winheight(0)/2)>a:tolerance)  
  exe 'norm! zz'  
 endif  
endfunction  
```  
thanks to both @PeterRincker @ZyX. I checked your answer because I found the Plug thing confusing, so I just took the `abs()` line and put it in the function. thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

```
nmap            n                          <Plug>VimrcSearch<Plug>VimrcZZifnotinmiddle
nnoremap        <Plug>VimrcSearch          n
nnoremap <expr> <Plug>VimrcZZifnotinmiddle (abs(winline()-winheight(0)/2)>5 ? 'zz' : '')."\<C-l>"
```

The above three lines are result of the following workarounds:

1. First `<Plug>` and second line is a) for avoiding remapping (really to avoid remembering cases where part of remappable mappings are not remapped) b) to follow the rule “when using remappable mapping each symbol in the {rhs} must be remapped in a known way”.
2. Second `<Plug>` and third line is there because `<expr>` mapping must be launched *after* switching to new position. I can’t put `n` in the `<expr>` mapping because second part with the `zz` condition will be evaluated before switching to new position.

There is an alternative:

```
    nnoremap <silent> n n:if abs(winline()-winheight(0)/2)>5<bar>execute 'normal! zz'<bar>endif<CR>
```

, but `<expr>` mapping was the first thing that came to my mind hence I’ll keep it.

Answer (score 1):

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_search_results_appear_in_the_middle_of_the_screen

Answer (score -1):

```
function! CenterWhenNotAtTheMiddle()
    let currentLine = winline() 
    let offsetFromMiddleLine = 5
    let lineBeforeTenMiddleLines = winheight(0) / 2 - offsetFromMiddleLine
    let lineAfterTenMiddleLines = winheight(0) / 2 + offsetFromMiddleLine
    if currentLine < lineBeforeTenMiddleLines 
        normal zz
    else
        if currentLine > linesAfterTenMiddleLines
            normal zz
        endif
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap n n:call CenterWhenNotAtTheMiddle()<Cr>
nnoremap N N:call CenterWhenNotAtTheMiddle()<Cr>
```

Comment: Exactly my second solution, but thirteen lines larger. You don’t need more then one variable here. Neither you need two conditions: is it really that hard to remember `abs()` being short for “*abs*olute value”? And why do you use `middleLinesAmount` which looks like being used for avoiding magic number if you put that magic number into two second variable names?

Comment: The variables exist in order to make the code easier to understand, which I prefer when posting answers. There might be people reading the answer who have trouble understanding more terse code.

Comment: It does not make code more readable, not by a tiny bit. Vim already has descriptive function names, they are enough in this case. Your variant just raises the questions “WTF is ‘point’? Why points are compared to lines?”. More, looking at how you use the two point* variables it is obvious that both “points” are *included* in the ten middle lines, but it is stated they are *before* and *after* meaning *excluded*. One description of “what is winline()” function in a comment will be more then enough in case you think it is not obvious what is meant.

Comment: And “middleLinesAmount” is really “offset from the middle of the screen”, because amount of middle lines is ten, not five.

Comment: @ZyX, thanks for the good suggestions. I changed the answer accordingly, but I left in the two conditions since it's a bit more easier to understand and your answer shows the abs way of doing it.

Comment: They are still *before* and *after* while lines are *first* and *last* (like `firstMiddleLine`). They were *before* and *after* if you used less/greater then or equal to operator and `(offsetFromMiddle-1)` instead of `offsetFromMiddle`. And two nested if’s are normally written as `if ... elseif ... endif`. But in this case you as well have unneeded duplicate `normal! zz`: the conditions should be joined as in this case it is easier to refactor it, for example, generalizing to “CallIfNotInMiddle(funcref)”, or adding other needed stuff (for example code that highlights old cursor line).